Why did apt-get dist-upgrade remove gdm3, gnome, nautilus, and the entire desktop environment?
I am using Debian testing (trixie). A few days ago, I ran apt-get dist-upgrade to update my system. I will be frank: it slipped my attention that more than half of the proposed package changes were to be removed.
Well, apt proceeded to remove the entire desktop environment!
I eventually fixed the issue, but I am still wondering: why did apt remove all these packages?
Between the last two updates, I had installed libldap2-dev and libsasl2-dev, while I had auto-removed jbig2dec.

Below is the respective log entry that removed important packages.
# /var/log/apt/history.log
Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
Install: libgts-0.7-5t64:amd64 (0.7.6+darcs121130-5.2, automatic), libhwy1t64:amd64 (1.0.7-8.1, automatic), libpangomm-2.48-1t64:amd64 (2.52.0-1, automatic), libgail18t64:amd64 (2.24.33-4, automatic), libtirpc3t64:amd64 (1.3.4+ds-1.3, automatic), libmtp9t64:amd64 (1.1.21-3.1, automatic), libglibmm-2.4-1t64:amd64 (2.66.7-1, automatic), libpsl5t64:amd64 (0.21.2-1.1, automatic), libext2fs2t64:amd64 (1.47.0-2.4, automatic), libpython3.11t64:amd64 (3.11.9-1, automatic), libgtk2.0-0t64:amd64 (2.24.33-4, automatic), libzzip-0-13t64:amd64 (0.13.72+dfsg.1-1.2+b1, automatic), libglibmm-2.68-1t64:amd64 (2.78.1-2.2, automatic), libburn4t64:amd64 (1.5.6-1.1, automatic), libcups2t64:amd64 (2.4.7-1.2+b1, automatic), libatspi2.0-0t64:amd64 (2.52.0-1, automatic), libcurl3t64-gnutls:amd64 (8.7.1-3, automatic), libarchive13t64:amd64 (3.7.2-2, automatic), libssh2-1t64:amd64 (1.11.0-4.1+b2, automatic), libmbedcrypto7t64:amd64 (2.28.8-1, automatic), libxt6t64:amd64 (1:1.2.1-1.2, automatic), policykit-1-gnome:amd64 (0.105-8+b1, automatic), libdvdread8t64:amd64 (6.1.3-1.1, automatic), libcurl4t64:amd64 (8.7.1-3, automatic), libatk1.0-0t64:amd64 (2.52.0-1, automatic), libapt-pkg6.0t64:amd64 (2.9.2, automatic), libabsl20230802:amd64 (20230802.1-4, automatic), libruby3.1t64:amd64 (3.1.2-8.3, automatic), libisofs6t64:amd64 (1.5.6.pl01-1.1, automatic), libgtk-3-0t64:amd64 (3.24.41-4, automatic), libatk-bridge2.0-0t64:amd64 (2.52.0-1, automatic), libapr1t64:amd64 (1.7.2-3.2, automatic), libept1.6.0t64:amd64 (1.2.1+nmu1, automatic), libglib2.0-0t64:amd64 (2.78.4-7, automatic), libmtdev1t64:amd64 (1.1.6-1.2, automatic)
Upgrade: libnetfilter-conntrack3:amd64 (1.0.9-6, 1.0.9-6+b1), gkbd-capplet:amd64 (3.28.1-1, 3.28.1-1+b1), libcogl-path20:amd64 (1.22.8-4+b1, 1.22.8-4+b2), libsynctex2:amd64 (2023.20230311.66589-9, 2023.20230311.66589-9+b2), gnome-text-editor:amd64 (46~beta-1, 46.1-1), network-manager-openvpn-gnome:amd64 (1.10.2-4, 1.10.2-4+b1), gir1.2-adw-1:amd64 (1.5~beta-1, 1.5.0-1), ruby-sdbm:amd64 (1.0.0-5+b2, 1.0.0-5+b4), swell-foop:amd64 (1:41.1-1+b1, 1:46.0-1), hitori:amd64 (44.0-2, 44.0-2+b1), tecla:amd64 (46~beta-1, 46.0-1), libb2-1:amd64 (0.98.1-1.1, 0.98.1-1.1+b1), libltc11:amd64 (1.3.2-1, 1.3.2-1+b1), gir1.2-geocodeglib-2.0:amd64 (3.26.3-6+b1, 3.26.3-6+b2), libvpx8:amd64 (1.13.1-2, 1.13.1-2+b1), libpam-gnome-keyring:amd64 (42.1-1+b2, 46.1-2), libsecret-1-0:amd64 (0.21.4-1, 0.21.4-1+b1), python3.11:amd64 (3.11.8-1, 3.11.9-1), python3.12:amd64 (3.12.2-1, 3.12.3-1), libltdl7:amd64 (2.4.7-7, 2.4.7-7+b1), rygel-playbin:amd64 (0.42.5-1, 0.42.5-1+b1), libgsf-1-114:amd64 (1.14.51-2, 1.14.51-2+b1), libpaper1:amd64 (1.1.29, 1.1.29+b1), librygel-renderer-gst-2.8-0:amd64 (0.42.5-1, 0.42.5-1+b1), libmm-glib0:amd64 (1.22.0-3, 1.22.0-3+b1), python3-gi:amd64 (3.47.0-3, 3.48.2-1), libqrtr-glib0:amd64 (1.2.2-1, 1.2.2-1+b1), gir1.2-gmenu-3.0:amd64 (3.36.0-1.1+b1, 3.36.0-1.1+b2), gir1.2-rest-1.0:amd64 (0.9.1-6, 0.9.1-6+b1), libnftnl11:amd64 (1.2.6-2, 1.2.6-2+b1), libnma-gtk4-0:amd64 (1.10.6-2, 1.10.6-3), libmtp-common:amd64 (1.1.21-3, 1.1.21-3.1), network-manager-openvpn:amd64 (1.10.2-4, 1.10.2-4+b1), libgupnp-dlna-2.0-4:amd64 (0.12.0-4, 0.12.0-4+b1), libxres1:amd64 (2:1.2.1-1, 2:1.2.1-1+b1), nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal:amd64 (3.51.90-1, 3.52.0-1), libmbim-utils:amd64 (1.30.0-1, 1.30.0-1+b1), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin:amd64 (2.42.10+dfsg-3+b1, 2.42.10+dfsg-3+b3), libgcr-base-3-1:amd64 (3.41.2-1, 3.41.2-1+b1), gnome-sudoku:amd64 (1:46~beta-1, 1:46.0-1), libxklavier16:amd64 (5.4-5, 5.4-5+b1), va-driver-all:amd64 (2.20.0-2, 2.20.0-2+b1), libfreeaptx0:amd64 (0.1.1-2, 0.1.1-2+b1), libatkmm-1.6-1v5:amd64 (2.28.4-1, 2.28.4-1+b1), gnome-font-viewer:amd64 (45.0-1, 46.0-1), apt:amd64 (2.7.12, 2.9.2), network-manager-openconnect-gnome:amd64 (1.2.10-3, 1.2.10-3+b1), libxrender1:amd64 (1:0.9.10-1.1, 1:0.9.10-1.1+b1), webp-pixbuf-loader:amd64 (0.2.4-2+b1, 0.2.4-2+b2), dbus-user-session:amd64 (1.14.10-4, 1.14.10-4+b1), libepubgen-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.1-1, 0.1.1-1+b1), gir1.2-json-1.0:amd64 (1.8.0-2, 1.8.0-2+b1), libqmi-proxy:amd64 (1.34.0-2, 1.34.0-2+b1), libatk-wrapper-java-jni:amd64 (0.40.0-3+b1, 0.40.0-3+b2), libtexlua53-5:amd64 (2023.20230311.66589-9, 2023.20230311.66589-9+b2), libglvnd0:amd64 (1.7.0-1, 1.7.0-1+b1), gnome-user-share:amd64 (43.0-1, 43.0-1+b1), libraptor2-0:amd64 (2.0.16-3+b1, 2.0.16-3+b2), libabw-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.3-1, 0.1.3-1+b1), gnome-klotski:amd64 (1:3.38.2-1+b1, 1:3.38.2-1+b2), gir1.2-notify-0.7:amd64 (0.8.3-1, 0.8.3-1+b1), libetonyek-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.10-5, 0.1.10-5+b1), gcr:amd64 (3.41.2-1, 3.41.2-1+b1), modemmanager:amd64 (1.22.0-3, 1.22.0-3+b1), git:amd64 (1:2.43.0-1, 1:2.43.0-1+b1), texlive-binaries:amd64 (2023.20230311.66589-9, 2023.20230311.66589-9+b2), avahi-autoipd:amd64 (0.8-13+b1, 0.8-13+b2), libtirpc-common:amd64 (1.3.4+ds-1, 1.3.4+ds-1.3), tzdata:amd64 (2024a-1, 2024a-3), libx11-xcb1:amd64 (2:1.8.7-1, 2:1.8.7-1+b1), libxshmfence1:amd64 (1.3-1, 1.3-1+b1), libunwind8:amd64 (1.6.2-3, 1.6.2-3+b1), librygel-core-2.8-0:amd64 (0.42.5-1, 0.42.5-1+b1), cups-common:amd64 (2.4.7-1, 2.4.7-1.2), libdecor-0-0:amd64 (0.2.2-1, 0.2.2-1+b1), libpango-1.0-0:amd64 (1.52.0+ds-1, 1.52.1+ds-1), libmatroska7:amd64 (1.7.1-1, 1.7.1-1+b1), python3-cffi-backend:amd64 (1.16.0-2+b1, 1.16.0-2+b2), libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1:amd64 (1.14.2-1+b1, 1.14.2-1+b2), libgusb2:amd64 (0.4.8-1, 0.4.8-1+b1), libgeocode-glib-2-0:amd64 (3.26.3-6+b1, 3.26.3-6+b2), python3-minimal:amd64 (3.11.6-1, 3.11.8-1), libmbim-glib4:amd64 (1.30.0-1, 1.30.0-1+b1), libxkbfile1:amd64 (1:1.1.0-1, 1:1.1.0-1+b1), libayatana-appindicator3-1:amd64 (0.5.93-1, 0.5.93-1+b1), libice-dev:amd64 (2:1.0.10-1, 2:1.0.10-1+b1), libselinux1:amd64 (3.5-2, 3.5-2+b2), python3-lib2to3:amd64 (3.11.5-1, 3.12.3-1), libplist3:amd64 (2.2.0-7, 2.2.0-7+b1), libgtksourceview-5-common:amd64 (5.11.1-2, 5.12.0-1), libgtk2.0-bin:amd64 (2.24.33-3, 2.24.33-4), gnome-color-manager:amd64 (3.36.0-2, 3.36.0-2+b1), libavahi-common-data:amd64 (0.8-13+b1, 0.8-13+b2), libheif1:amd64 (1.17.6-1, 1.17.6-1+b2), libcolord2:amd64 (1.4.7-1, 1.4.7-1+b1), python3-venv:amd64 (3.11.6-1, 3.11.8-1), libass9:amd64 (1:0.17.1-2, 1:0.17.1-2+b1), geoclue-2.0:amd64 (2.7.1-2, 2.7.1-2+b1), libgexiv2-2:amd64 (0.14.2-2+b1, 0.14.2-2+b2), libpciaccess0:amd64 (0.17-3, 0.17-3+b1), libconfig++9v5:amd64 (1.5-0.4, 1.5-0.4+b1), gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0:amd64 (3.0.27-3+b1, 3.0.27-4), libxcursor1:amd64 (1:1.2.1-1, 1:1.2.1-1+b1), libkpathsea6:amd64 (2023.20230311.66589-9, 2023.20230311.66589-9+b2), libbluray2:amd64 (1:1.3.4-1, 1:1.3.4-1+b1), libheif-plugin-libde265:amd64 (1.17.6-1, 1.17.6-1+b2), libconfuse2:amd64 (3.3-3, 3.3-3+b1), libgtop-2.0-11:amd64 (2.41.3-1, 2.41.3-1+b1), gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64 (2.42.10+dfsg-3+b1, 2.42.10+dfsg-3+b3), xdg-desktop-portal-gtk:amd64 (1.15.1-1, 1.15.1-1+b1), dconf-editor:amd64 (45.0.1-1, 45.0.1-1+b1), libavahi-core7:amd64 (0.8-13+b1, 0.8-13+b2), synaptic:amd64 (0.91.3, 0.91.3+b1), python3-pluggy:amd64 (1.4.0-1, 1.5.0-1), libxmuu1:amd64 (2:1.1.3-3, 2:1.1.3-3+b2), libpython3.12-minimal:amd64 (3.12.2-1, 3.12.3-1), libmypaint-1.5-1:amd64 (1.6.0-2, 1.6.0-2+b1), libapache2-mod-dnssd:amd64 (0.6-4, 0.6-4+b1), at-spi2-core:amd64 (2.50.0-1+b1, 2.52.0-1), libcogl20:amd64 (1.22.8-4+b1, 1.22.8-4+b2), libdee-1.0-4:amd64 (1.2.7+17.10.20170616-7+b2, 1.2.7+17.10.20170616-7+b3), cups-client:amd64 (2.4.7-1+b1, 2.4.7-1.2+b1), baobab:amd64 (45.0-1, 46.0-1), cups-ppdc:amd64 (2.4.7-1+b1, 2.4.7-1.2+b1), gir1.2-wnck-3.0:amd64 (43.0-3, 43.0-3+b1), libcolorhug2:amd64 (1.4.7-1, 1.4.7-1+b1), libglx0:amd64 (1.7.0-1, 1.7.0-1+b1), libgts-bin:amd64 (0.7.6+darcs121130-5+b1, 0.7.6+darcs121130-5.2), dbus-daemon:amd64 (1.14.10-4, 1.14.10-4+b1), libgcr-ui-3-1:amd64 (3.41.2-1, 3.41.2-1+b1), cups-daemon:amd64 (2.4.7-1+b1, 2.4.7-1.2+b1), libraw1394-11:amd64 (2.1.2-2, 2.1.2-2+b1), colord:amd64 (1.4.7-1, 1.4.7-1+b1), libmanette-0.2-0:amd64 (0.2.7-1, 0.2.7-1+b1), gnome-tweaks:amd64 (46~beta-2, 46.0-2), user-session-migration:amd64 (0.4.1, 0.4.2), libsigsegv2:amd64 (2.14-1, 2.14-1+b1), libinput10:amd64 (1.25.0-1, 1.25.0-1+b2), gnome-system-monitor:amd64 (46~beta-1, 46.0-1), libva-x11-2:amd64 (2.20.0-2, 2.20.0-2+b1), librist4:amd64 (0.2.10+dfsg-1, 0.2.10+dfsg-2), python3-pikepdf:amd64 (8.14.0+dfsg-1, 8.15.1+dfsg-1), libgsm1:amd64 (1.0.22-1, 1.0.22-1+b1), libgupnp-1.6-0:amd64 (1.6.6-1+b1, 1.6.6-1+b2), libsm-dev:amd64 (2:1.2.3-1, 2:1.2.3-1+b1), libxau6:amd64 (1:1.0.9-1, 1:1.0.9-1+b1), libxaw7:amd64 (2:1.0.14-1, 2:1.0.14-1+b2), libclutter-gtk-1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.4-4+b1, 1.8.4-4+b2), avahi-daemon:amd64 (0.8-13+b1, 0.8-13+b2), libgtkmm-4.0-0:amd64 (4.10.0-4+b1, 4.10.0-4+b2), librsvg2-common:amd64 (2.54.7+dfsg-2, 2.58.0+dfsg-1), libxcomposite1:amd64 (1:0.4.5-1, 1:0.4.5-1+b1), libmpcdec6:amd64 (2:0.1~r495-2, 2:0.1~r495-2+b1), libtomcrypt1:amd64 (1.18.2+dfsg-7, 1.18.2+dfsg-7+b1), libgspell-1-2:amd64 (1.12.2-1+b1, 1.12.2-1+b2), python3:amd64 (3.11.6-1, 3.11.8-1), libatasmart4:amd64 (0.19-5, 0.19-5+b1), system-config-printer-udev:amd64 (1.5.18-1, 1.5.18-2), python3.11-venv:amd64 (3.11.8-1, 3.11.9-1), libdbus-1-3:amd64 (1.14.10-4, 1.14.10-4+b1), x11-utils:amd64 (7.7+6, 7.7+6+b1), libxdamage1:amd64 (1:1.1.6-1, 1:1.1.6-1+b1), libpython3.11-minimal:amd64 (3.11.8-1, 3.11.9-1), libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:amd64 (2.42.10+dfsg-3+b1, 2.42.10+dfsg-3+b3), dbus-bin:amd64 (1.14.10-4, 1.14.10-4+b1), libdvbpsi10:amd64 (1.3.3-1, 1.3.3-1+b1), zlib1g-dev:amd64 (1:1.3.dfsg-3+b1, 1:1.3.dfsg-3.1), libwmf-0.2-7:amd64 (0.2.13-1.1, 0.2.13-1.1+b2), libodfgen-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.8-2, 0.1.8-2+b1), aisleriot:amd64 (1:3.22.23-1, 1:3.22.31-1+b3), libsepol2:amd64 (3.5-2, 3.5-2+b1), libmnl0:amd64 (1.0.5-2, 1.0.5-2+b1), gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 (3.24.41-1, 3.24.41-4), libgupnp-igd-1.6-0:amd64 (1.6.0-3+b1, 1.6.0-3+b2), libxml2:amd64 (2.9.14+dfsg-1.3+b2, 2.9.14+dfsg-1.3+b3), librygel-server-2.8-0:amd64 (0.42.5-1, 0.42.5-1+b1), switcheroo-control:amd64 (2.6-2, 2.6-2+b1), libxmu6:amd64 (2:1.1.3-3, 2:1.1.3-3+b2), libxau-dev:amd64 (1:1.0.9-1, 1:1.0.9-1+b1), gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0:amd64 (1.2.8-2, 1.2.8-2+b2), libglib2.0-data:amd64 (2.78.4-1, 2.78.4-7), network-manager-gnome:amd64 (1.34.0-2, 1.36.0-1), libgtk2.0-common:amd64 (2.24.33-3, 2.24.33-4), libgee-0.8-2:amd64 (0.20.6-1, 0.20.6-1+b1), python-apt-common:amd64 (2.7.6, 2.8.0), libdconf1:amd64 (0.40.0-4+b1, 0.40.0-4+b2), libxpm4:amd64 (1:3.5.17-1, 1:3.5.17-1+b1), libnma-common:amd64 (1.10.6-2, 1.10.6-3), libvdpau1:amd64 (1.5-2, 1.5-2+b1), libmodplug1:amd64 (1:0.8.9.0-3, 1:0.8.9.0-3+b1), libgav1-1:amd64 (0.18.0-1+b1, 0.19.0-2+b1), libgpg-error0:amd64 (1.47-3, 1.47-3+b1), libxss1:amd64 (1:1.2.3-1, 1:1.2.3-1+b1), libxcvt0:amd64 (0.1.2-1, 0.1.2-1+b1), gir1.2-geoclue-2.0:amd64 (2.7.1-2, 2.7.1-2+b1), libshumate-1.0-1:amd64 (1.2~beta-3, 1.2~beta-3+b1), network-manager-openconnect:amd64 (1.2.10-3, 1.2.10-3+b1), libcdr-0.1-1:amd64 (0.1.7-1, 0.1.7-1+b1), libgles2:amd64 (1.7.0-1, 1.7.0-1+b1), power-profiles-daemon:amd64 (0.20-3, 0.21-1), cups-ipp-utils:amd64 (2.4.7-1+b1, 2.4.7-1.2+b1), libyaml-0-2:amd64 (0.2.5-1, 0.2.5-1+b1), libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0:amd64 (0.12.21-1, 0.12.21-1+b1), gnome-mines:amd64 (1:40.1-1+b1, 1:40.1-1+b2), libheif-plugin-x265:amd64 (1.17.6-1, 1.17.6-1+b2), libcom-err2:amd64 (1.47.0-2+b1, 1.47.0-2.4), python3-pycurl:amd64 (7.45.2-7, 7.45.3-2), libheif-plugin-aomenc:amd64 (1.17.6-1, 1.17.6-1+b2), libxxf86dga1:amd64 (2:1.1.5-1, 2:1.1.5-1+b1), libjxl0.7:amd64 (0.7.0-10.2+b1, 0.7.0-10.2+b3), network-manager-vpnc-gnome:amd64 (1.2.8-7, 1.2.8-7+b1), libxfont2:amd64 (1:2.0.6-1, 1:2.0.6-1+b1), gnome-logs:amd64 (45~beta-2, 45.0-1), libpagemaker-0.0-0:amd64 (0.0.4-1, 0.0.4-1+b1), python3-hypothesis:amd64 (6.100.1-2, 6.100.1-3), libpangomm-1.4-1v5:amd64 (2.46.4-1, 2.46.4-1+b1), libassuan0:amd64 (2.5.6-1, 2.5.6-1+b1), libsoxr0:amd64 (0.1.3-4, 0.1.3-4+b1), system-config-printer-common:amd64 (1.5.18-1, 1.5.18-2), gir1.2-graphene-1.0:amd64 (1.10.8-3, 1.10.8-3+b1), libsoup-3.0-0:amd64 (3.4.4-5, 3.4.4-5+b1), libptexenc1:amd64 (2023.20230311.66589-9, 2023.20230311.66589-9+b2), libavc1394-0:amd64 (0.5.4-5, 0.5.4-5+b1), libsodium23:amd64 (1.0.18-1, 1.0.18-1+b1), libudfread0:amd64 (1.1.2-1, 1.1.2-1+b1), gnome-calculator:amd64 (1:46~beta-1, 1:46.0-1), gnome-2048:amd64 (3.38.2-3+b1, 3.38.2-3+b2), libwmflite-0.2-7:amd64 (0.2.13-1.1, 0.2.13-1.1+b2), libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64 (1.52.0+ds-1, 1.52.1+ds-1), libndp0:amd64 (1.8-1, 1.8-1+b1), file-roller:amd64 (43.1-1, 44.1-1), libxkbcommon0:amd64 (1.6.0-1, 1.6.0-1+b1), libxtst6:amd64 (2:1.2.3-1.1, 2:1.2.3-1.1+b1), vdpau-driver-all:amd64 (1.5-2, 1.5-2+b1), libgnome-menu-3-0:amd64 (3.36.0-1.1+b1, 3.36.0-1.1+b2), libmysofa1:amd64 (1.3.2+dfsg-2, 1.3.2+dfsg-2+b1), libatk-adaptor:amd64 (2.50.0-1+b1, 2.52.0-1), libprotobuf-c1:amd64 (1.4.1-1+b1, 1.4.1-1+b2), dconf-cli:amd64 (0.40.0-4+b1, 0.40.0-4+b2), gir1.2-peas-1.0:amd64 (1.36.0-3, 1.36.0-3+b1), gir1.2-gtksource-4:amd64 (4.8.4-5+b1, 4.8.4-5+b2), libvte-2.91-common:amd64 (0.75.91-2, 0.75.92-1), libwps-0.4-4:amd64 (0.4.14-2, 0.4.14-2+b1), libharfbuzz-icu0:amd64 (8.3.0-2, 8.3.0-2+b1), xwayland:amd64 (2:23.2.4-1, 2:23.2.6-1), libvisual-0.4-0:amd64 (0.4.2-2, 0.4.2-2+b1), libgssdp-1.6-0:amd64 (1.6.3-1+b1, 1.6.3-1+b2), libgcrypt20:amd64 (1.10.3-2, 1.10.3-2+b1), libnotify4:amd64 (0.8.3-1, 0.8.3-1+b1), libnma0:amd64 (1.10.6-2, 1.10.6-3), libteamdctl0:amd64 (1.31-1, 1.31-1+b1), x11-session-utils:amd64 (7.7+6, 7.7+6+b1), libgupnp-av-1.0-3:amd64 (0.14.1-2, 0.14.1-2+b1), libdecor-0-plugin-1-gtk:amd64 (0.2.2-1, 0.2.2-1+b1), gnome-mahjongg:amd64 (1:3.40.0-1, 1:3.40.1-1), sshfs:amd64 (3.7.3-1.1, 3.7.3-1.1+b1), libgrilo-0.3-0:amd64 (0.3.16-1+b1, 0.3.16-1+b2), gir1.2-shumate-1.0:amd64 (1.2~beta-3, 1.2~beta-3+b1), libmbim-proxy:amd64 (1.30.0-1, 1.30.0-1+b1), xcvt:amd64 (0.1.2-1, 0.1.2-1+b1), libsemanage2:amd64 (3.5-1+b2, 3.5-1+b3), libice6:amd64 (2:1.0.10-1, 2:1.0.10-1+b1), gnome-disk-utility:amd64 (45.1-1, 46.0-1+b3), gir1.2-handy-1:amd64 (1.8.3-1, 1.8.3-1+b1), libcue2:amd64 (2.2.1-4.1, 2.2.1-4.1+b1), libasyncns0:amd64 (0.8-6+b3, 0.8-6+b4), libnsl2:amd64 (1.3.0-3, 1.3.0-3+b2), libunibreak5:amd64 (5.1-2, 5.1-2+b1), libpangoft2-1.0-0:amd64 (1.52.0+ds-1, 1.52.1+ds-1), libqmi-utils:amd64 (1.34.0-2, 1.34.0-2+b1), plymouth:amd64 (24.004.60-1, 24.004.60-1+b2), libpython3.11-stdlib:amd64 (3.11.8-1, 3.11.9-1), python3-apt:amd64 (2.7.6, 2.8.0), libgnome-games-support-1-3:amd64 (1.8.2-5, 1.8.2-5+b1), libstaroffice-0.0-0:amd64 (0.0.7-1, 0.0.7-1+b1), xdg-user-dirs-gtk:amd64 (0.11-1, 0.11-1+b1), libgnome-games-support-2-4:amd64 (2.0.0-2, 2.0.0-2+b1), libopengl0:amd64 (1.7.0-1, 1.7.0-1+b1), enchant-2:amd64 (2.3.3-2+b1, 2.3.3-2+b2), libnfs14:amd64 (5.0.2-1, 5.0.2-1+b1), librest-1.0-0:amd64 (0.9.1-6, 0.9.1-6+b1), zenity:amd64 (4.0.1-1, 4.0.1-1+b1), libkate1:amd64 (0.4.1-11, 0.4.1-11+b1), libpackagekit-glib2-18:amd64 (1.2.8-2, 1.2.8-2+b2), rygel:amd64 (0.42.5-1, 0.42.5-1+b1), libsidplay1v5:amd64 (1.36.60-1, 1.36.60-1+b1), liblangtag1:amd64 (0.6.7-1, 0.6.7-1+b1), libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.35-1, 1.1.35-1+b1), gir1.2-mediaart-2.0:amd64 (1.9.6-1, 1.9.6-1+b1), cups-pk-helper:amd64 (0.2.6-1+b1, 0.2.6-1+b2), x11-xkb-utils:amd64 (7.7+8, 7.7+8+b1), libglu1-mesa:amd64 (9.0.2-1.1, 9.0.2-1.1+b1), gnome-tetravex:amd64 (1:3.38.2-3, 1:3.38.2-3+b1), libmwaw-0.3-3:amd64 (0.3.22-1, 0.3.22-1+b1), libdca0:amd64 (0.0.7-2, 0.0.7-2+b1), libavahi-common3:amd64 (0.8-13+b1, 0.8-13+b2), libwmf-bin:amd64 (0.2.13-1.1, 0.2.13-1.1+b2), gir1.2-atk-1.0:amd64 (2.50.0-1+b1, 2.52.0-1), liblrdf0:amd64 (0.6.1-4, 0.6.1-4+b1), librsvg2-2:amd64 (2.54.7+dfsg-2, 2.58.0+dfsg-1), libxml++2.6-2v5:amd64 (2.42.3-1, 2.42.3-1+b1), libnumbertext-1.0-0:amd64 (1.0.11-4, 1.0.11-4+b1), libgtksourceview-4-0:amd64 (4.8.4-5+b1, 4.8.4-5+b2), libsamplerate0:amd64 (0.2.2-4, 0.2.2-4+b1), gnome-keyring:amd64 (42.1-1+b2, 46.1-2), libqmi-glib5:amd64 (1.34.0-2, 1.34.0-2+b1), libimagequant0:amd64 (2.18.0-1, 2.18.0-1+b1), libgtksourceview-5-0:amd64 (5.11.1-2, 5.12.0-1), five-or-more:amd64 (1:3.32.3-1+b1, 1:3.32.3-1+b2), libpython3.11-dev:amd64 (3.11.8-1, 3.11.9-1), libldacbt-enc2:amd64 (2.0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4, 2.0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4+b1), libbdplus0:amd64 (0.2.0-3, 0.2.0-3+b1), librevenge-0.0-0:amd64 (0.0.5-3, 0.0.5-3+b1), libxkbregistry0:amd64 (1.6.0-1, 1.6.0-1+b1), libgnome-autoar-gtk-0-0:amd64 (0.4.4-2+b1, 0.4.4-2+b2), libogg0:amd64 (1.3.5-3, 1.3.5-3+b1), gnome-menus:amd64 (3.36.0-1.1+b1, 3.36.0-1.1+b2), libx11-dev:amd64 (2:1.8.7-1, 2:1.8.7-1+b1), libavif16:amd64 (1.0.4-1, 1.0.4-2), libxinerama1:amd64 (2:1.1.4-3, 2:1.1.4-3+b1), gir1.2-pango-1.0:amd64 (1.52.0+ds-1, 1.52.1+ds-1), libpthread-stubs0-dev:amd64 (0.4-1, 0.4-1+b1), libytnef0:amd64 (2.1.2-1, 2.1.2-1+b1), libwnck-3-0:amd64 (43.0-3, 43.0-3+b1), libopenjp2-7:amd64 (2.5.0-2+b2, 2.5.0-2+b3), libpython3-stdlib:amd64 (3.11.6-1, 3.11.8-1), ruby3.1:amd64 (3.1.2-8, 3.1.2-8.3), x11-apps:amd64 (7.7+11, 7.7+11+b1), libdaemon0:amd64 (0.14-7.1, 0.14-7.1+b1), libjson-glib-1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.0-2, 1.8.0-2+b1), x11-xserver-utils:amd64 (7.7+10, 7.7+10+b1), libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64 (18.10.20180917~bzr492+repack1-3.1, 18.10.20180917~bzr492+repack1-3.1+b1), libosinfo-1.0-0:amd64 (1.11.0-2, 1.11.0-2+b1), apt-transport-https:amd64 (2.7.12, 2.9.2), libtommath1:amd64 (1.2.1-2, 1.2.1-2+b1), libpaper-utils:amd64 (1.1.29, 1.1.29+b1), libjaylink0:amd64 (0.3.1-1, 0.3.1-1+b1), python3.11-minimal:amd64 (3.11.8-1, 3.11.9-1), librygel-db-2.8-0:amd64 (0.42.5-1, 0.42.5-1+b1), simple-scan:amd64 (44.0-1, 44.0-1+b1), python3.11-dev:amd64 (3.11.8-1, 3.11.9-1), gtk2-engines-pixbuf:amd64 (2.24.33-3, 2.24.33-4), dconf-gsettings-backend:amd64 (0.40.0-4+b1, 0.40.0-4+b2), cups-core-drivers:amd64 (2.4.7-1+b1, 2.4.7-1.2+b1), libusbmuxd6:amd64 (2.0.2-4, 2.0.2-4+b1), libyelp0:amd64 (42.2-1+b1, 42.2-1+b2), libavahi-glib1:amd64 (0.8-13+b1, 0.8-13+b2), gnome-terminal-data:amd64 (3.51.90-1, 3.52.0-1), libadwaita-1-0:amd64 (1.5~beta-1, 1.5.0-1), yelp:amd64 (42.2-1+b1, 42.2-1+b2), libharfbuzz-gobject0:amd64 (8.3.0-2, 8.3.0-2+b1), libxt-dev:amd64 (1:1.2.1-1.1, 1:1.2.1-1.2), libva-wayland2:amd64 (2.20.0-2, 2.20.0-2+b1), plymouth-label:amd64 (24.004.60-1, 24.004.60-1+b2), network-manager-vpnc:amd64 (1.2.8-7, 1.2.8-7+b1), python3-distutils:amd64 (3.11.5-1, 3.12.3-1), gir1.2-rsvg-2.0:amd64 (2.54.7+dfsg-2, 2.58.0+dfsg-1), gtk-update-icon-cache:amd64 (3.24.41-1, 3.24.41-4), libsrtp2-1:amd64 (2.5.0-3, 2.5.0-3+b1), libgtk-3-common:amd64 (3.24.41-1, 3.24.41-4), libchamplain-0.12-0:amd64 (0.12.21-1, 0.12.21-1+b1), tilda:amd64 (2.0.0-1, 2.0.0-1+b1), libheif-plugin-dav1d:amd64 (1.17.6-1, 1.17.6-1+b2), gir1.2-soup-3.0:amd64 (3.4.4-5, 3.4.4-5+b1), libdvdnav4:amd64 (6.1.1-1, 6.1.1-3), libdc1394-25:amd64 (2.2.6-4, 2.2.6-4+b1), libgsf-bin:amd64 (1.14.51-2, 1.14.51-2+b1), libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 (1.36.0-3, 1.36.0-3+b1), libcogl-pango20:amd64 (1.22.8-4+b1, 1.22.8-4+b2), librygel-renderer-2.8-0:amd64 (0.42.5-1, 0.42.5-1+b1), libnice10:amd64 (0.1.21-2, 0.1.21-2+b1), libharfbuzz0b:amd64 (8.3.0-2, 8.3.0-2+b1), libxdmcp-dev:amd64 (1:1.1.2-3, 1:1.1.2-3+b1), python3-cups:amd64 (2.0.1-5+b5, 2.0.1-5+b6), libinstpatch-1.0-2:amd64 (1.1.6-1, 1.1.6-1+b1), libgtk-3-bin:amd64 (3.24.41-1, 3.24.41-4), apt-utils:amd64 (2.7.12, 2.9.2), gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0:amd64 (3.26.6-1+b1, 3.26.6-1+b2), gnome-terminal:amd64 (3.51.90-1, 3.52.0-1), opensc:amd64 (0.25.0~rc1-1, 0.25.0~rc1-1+b1), libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:amd64 (18.10.20180917~bzr492+repack1-3.1, 18.10.20180917~bzr492+repack1-3.1+b1), libhandy-1-0:amd64 (1.8.3-1, 1.8.3-1+b1), tali:amd64 (1:40.9-1+b1, 1:40.9-1+b2), libxvmc1:amd64 (2:1.0.12-2, 2:1.0.12-2+b1), cups:amd64 (2.4.7-1+b1, 2.4.7-1.2+b1), curl:amd64 (8.5.0-2, 8.7.1-3), sysvinit-utils:amd64 (3.08-7, 3.09-1), libenchant-2-2:amd64 (2.3.3-2+b1, 2.3.3-2+b2), logsave:amd64 (1.47.0-2+b1, 1.47.0-2.4), libpangoxft-1.0-0:amd64 (1.52.0+ds-1, 1.52.1+ds-1), libva-drm2:amd64 (2.20.0-2, 2.20.0-2+b1), gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0:amd64 (8.3.0-2, 8.3.0-2+b1), iio-sensor-proxy:amd64 (3.5-1+b1, 3.5-1+b2), libplymouth5:amd64 (24.004.60-1, 24.004.60-1+b2), libgnomekbd8:amd64 (3.28.1-1, 3.28.1-1+b1), gnome-themes-extra:amd64 (3.28-2+b1, 3.28-2+b2), python3.12-minimal:amd64 (3.12.2-1, 3.12.3-1), dconf-service:amd64 (0.40.0-4+b1, 0.40.0-4+b2), libgl1:amd64 (1.7.0-1, 1.7.0-1+b1), libegl1:amd64 (1.7.0-1, 1.7.0-1+b1), realmd:amd64 (0.17.1-3, 0.17.1-3+b1), gnome-keyring-pkcs11:amd64 (42.1-1+b2, 46.1-2), zlib1g:amd64 (1:1.3.dfsg-3+b1, 1:1.3.dfsg-3.1), libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.8.7-1, 2:1.8.7-1+b1), libdbus-glib-1-2:amd64 (0.112-3+b1, 0.112-3+b2), gir1.2-grilo-0.3:amd64 (0.3.16-1+b1, 0.3.16-1+b2), gnome-chess:amd64 (1:46~beta-1, 1:46.0-1), libmediaart-2.0-0:amd64 (1.9.6-1, 1.9.6-1+b1), libgraphene-1.0-0:amd64 (1.10.8-3, 1.10.8-3+b1), opensc-pkcs11:amd64 (0.25.0~rc1-1, 0.25.0~rc1-1+b1), libgnome-autoar-0-0:amd64 (0.4.4-2+b1, 0.4.4-2+b2), libldacbt-abr2:amd64 (2.0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4, 2.0.2.3+git20200429+ed310a0-4+b1), python3-dbus:amd64 (1.3.2-5+b1, 1.3.2-5+b2), libxkbcommon-x11-0:amd64 (1.6.0-1, 1.6.0-1+b1), xterm:amd64 (390-1, 390-1+b1), xdg-dbus-proxy:amd64 (0.1.5-1, 0.1.5-1+b1), cups-server-common:amd64 (2.4.7-1, 2.4.7-1.2), groff-base:amd64 (1.23.0-3, 1.23.0-3+b1), libvte-2.91-0:amd64 (0.75.91-2, 0.75.92-1), libclutter-1.0-0:amd64 (1.26.4+git2779b932+dfsg-7, 1.26.4+git2779b932+dfsg-7+b1), libwpg-0.3-3:amd64 (0.3.4-3, 0.3.4-3+b1), libtalloc2:amd64 (2.4.2-1, 2.4.2-1+b1), dbus:amd64 (1.14.10-4, 1.14.10-4+b1), libimobiledevice6:amd64 (1.3.0-7.1, 1.3.0-7.1+b1), libgeoclue-2-0:amd64 (2.7.1-2, 2.7.1-2+b1), libgck-1-0:amd64 (3.41.2-1, 3.41.2-1+b1), libpython3.12-stdlib:amd64 (3.12.2-1, 3.12.3-1), libedit2:amd64 (3.1-20230828-1, 3.1-20230828-1+b1), gir1.2-secret-1:amd64 (0.21.4-1, 0.21.4-1+b1), at-spi2-common:amd64 (2.50.0-1, 2.52.0-1), liblqr-1-0:amd64 (0.4.2-2.1, 0.4.2-2.1+b1), libavahi-client3:amd64 (0.8-13+b1, 0.8-13+b2), liblinear4:amd64 (2.3.0+dfsg-5, 2.3.0+dfsg-5+b1), low-memory-monitor:amd64 (2.1-2, 2.1-2+b1), libfstrm0:amd64 (0.6.1-1+b1, 0.6.1-1+b2), libsm6:amd64 (2:1.2.3-1, 2:1.2.3-1+b1), libss2:amd64 (1.47.0-2+b1, 1.47.0-2.4), python3-cupshelpers:amd64 (1.5.18-1, 1.5.18-2), libclutter-gst-3.0-0:amd64 (3.0.27-3+b1, 3.0.27-4), libtotem-plparser18:amd64 (3.26.6-1+b1, 3.26.6-1+b2), python3-gi-cairo:amd64 (3.47.0-3, 3.48.2-1), libva2:amd64 (2.20.0-2, 2.20.0-2+b1), gir1.2-nma4-1.0:amd64 (1.10.6-2, 1.10.6-3), gir1.2-atspi-2.0:amd64 (2.50.0-1+b1, 2.52.0-1), libxfixes3:amd64 (1:6.0.0-2, 1:6.0.0-2+b1), libayatana-indicator3-7:amd64 (0.9.3-1.1, 0.9.4-1), libxdmcp6:amd64 (1:1.1.2-3, 1:1.1.2-3+b1), libmtp-runtime:amd64 (1.1.21-3, 1.1.21-3.1), libdebconfclient0:amd64 (0.271+b1, 0.271+b3), libxv1:amd64 (2:1.0.11-1.1, 2:1.0.11-1.1+b1), libgail-common:amd64 (2.24.33-3, 2.24.33-4), libbrasero-media3-1:amd64 (3.12.3-2+b2, 3.12.3-2+b5), libutempter0:amd64 (1.2.1-3, 1.2.1-3+b1), e2fsprogs:amd64 (1.47.0-2+b1, 1.47.0-2.4), lightsoff:amd64 (1:40.0.1-1, 1:46.0-1), libinput-bin:amd64 (1.25.0-1, 1.25.0-1+b2), libspectre1:amd64 (0.2.12-1, 0.2.12-1+b1), liboauth0:amd64 (1.0.3-5, 1.0.3-5+b1), libevdev2:amd64 (1.13.1+dfsg-1, 1.13.1+dfsg-1+b1)
Remove: libssh2-1:amd64 (1.11.0-4), tracker:amd64 (3.4.2-3), libcups2:amd64 (2.4.7-1+b1), libglibmm-2.68-1:amd64 (2.78.1-1), libcurl4:amd64 (8.5.0-2), libext2fs2:amd64 (1.47.0-2+b1), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (8.5.0-2), packagekit-tools:amd64 (1.2.8-2), gnome-software:amd64 (46~beta-1), libisofs6:amd64 (1.5.6.pl01-1), gnome-weather:amd64 (46.0-1), libglib2.0-bin:amd64 (2.78.4-1), gstreamer1.0-packagekit:amd64 (1.2.8-2), libarchive13:amd64 (3.7.2-1), libapr1:amd64 (1.7.2-3+b2), libmbedcrypto7:amd64 (2.28.7-1), libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 (2.7.12), libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 (2.50.0-1+b1), software-properties-common:amd64 (0.99.30-4), tracker-miner-fs:amd64 (3.4.6-3), libmtdev1:amd64 (1.1.6-1+b1), gnome:amd64 (1:44+1), evolution-plugins:amd64 (3.50.3-1), libevolution:amd64 (3.50.3-1), libgail18:amd64 (2.24.33-3), gnome-shell-extensions:amd64 (44.0-2), gnome-shell:amd64 (44.9-1), libmtp9:amd64 (1.1.21-3), libruby3.1:amd64 (3.1.2-8), libpangomm-2.48-1:amd64 (2.50.1-5+b1), packagekit:amd64 (1.2.8-2), libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (2.24.33-3), gdm3:amd64 (45.0.1-3), libhwy1:amd64 (1.0.7-8+b1), libatk1.0-0:amd64 (2.50.0-1+b1), libpython3.11:amd64 (3.11.8-1), libatspi2.0-0:amd64 (2.50.0-1+b1), gnome-maps:amd64 (46~beta-1), evolution-plugin-pstimport:amd64 (3.50.3-1), software-properties-gtk:amd64 (0.99.30-4), libzzip-0-13:amd64 (0.13.72+dfsg.1-1.1+b1), evolution-plugin-bogofilter:amd64 (3.50.3-1), chrome-gnome-shell:amd64 (42.1-4), gnome-music:amd64 (46.0-1), libglibmm-2.4-1v5:amd64 (2.66.6-2+b1), tracker-extract:amd64 (3.4.6-3), evolution:amd64 (3.50.3-1), task-gnome-desktop:amd64 (3.75), libgail-3-0:amd64 (3.24.41-1), libept1.6.0:amd64 (1.2.1), libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.78.4-1), gnome-session:amd64 (45.0-2), libgtk-3-0:amd64 (3.24.41-1), gnome-browser-connector:amd64 (42.1-4), nautilus:amd64 (45.2.1-4), gnome-core:amd64 (1:44+1), gnome-characters:amd64 (45.0-2), gnome-sushi:amd64 (45.0-1), gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 (44.9-1), rygel-tracker:amd64 (0.42.5-1), libtirpc3:amd64 (1.3.4+ds-1), libdvdread8:amd64 (6.1.3-1), libpsl5:amd64 (0.21.2-1+b1), libgts-0.7-5:amd64 (0.7.6+darcs121130-5+b1), libxt6:amd64 (1:1.2.1-1.1), libburn4:amd64 (1.5.6-1)

And I subsequently proceeded to auto-remove the libraries as well.
# /var/log/apt/history.log
Commandline: apt-get autoremove
Remove: python3-blinker:amd64 (1.7.0-1), libosinfo-l10n:amd64 (1.11.0-2), gir1.2-geocodeglib-2.0:amd64 (3.26.3-6+b2), gir1.2-gmenu-3.0:amd64 (3.36.0-1.1+b2), gir1.2-rest-1.0:amd64 (0.9.1-6+b1), libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop:amd64 (7.1.4+19.04.20190319-6), gir1.2-json-1.0:amd64 (1.8.0-2+b1), gnome-software-common:amd64 (46~beta-1), python3-lazr.restfulclient:amd64 (0.14.6-1), libcmark0.30.2:amd64 (0.30.2-6+b1), osinfo-db:amd64 (0.20231215-1), libdee-1.0-4:amd64 (1.2.7+17.10.20170616-7+b3), gnome-session-bin:amd64 (45.0-2), gir1.2-tracker-3.0:amd64 (3.4.2-3), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.1:amd64 (2.42.5-1), gir1.2-webkit2-4.1:amd64 (2.42.5-1), python3-software-properties:amd64 (0.99.30-4), libshumate-common:amd64 (1.2~beta-3), python3-lazr.uri:amd64 (1.0.6-3), switcheroo-control:amd64 (2.6-2+b1), gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0:amd64 (1.2.8-2+b2), libiptcdata0:amd64 (1.0.5-2.3), gir1.2-geoclue-2.0:amd64 (2.7.1-2+b1), libshumate-1.0-1:amd64 (1.2~beta-3+b1), libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0:amd64 (0.12.21-1+b1), appstream:amd64 (1.0.2-1), python3-wadllib:amd64 (1.3.6-5), python3-oauthlib:amd64 (3.2.2-1), apt-config-icons:amd64 (1.0.2-1), gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64 (1.46.0-1), libunity9:amd64 (7.1.4+19.04.20190319-6+b1), gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0:amd64 (23.13.9-6), libgnome-menu-3-0:amd64 (3.36.0-1.1+b2), gir1.2-gtksource-4:amd64 (4.8.4-5+b2), gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0:amd64 (46~beta-1), xwayland:amd64 (2:23.2.6-1), p7zip-full:amd64 (16.02+transitional.1), gir1.2-mutter-12:amd64 (44.8-3), gir1.2-shumate-1.0:amd64 (1.2~beta-3+b1), gstreamer1.0-pipewire:amd64 (1.0.3-1), gir1.2-handy-1:amd64 (1.8.3-1+b1), libcue2:amd64 (2.2.1-4.1+b1), libnsl2:amd64 (1.3.0-3+b2), libunity-protocol-private0:amd64 (7.1.4+19.04.20190319-6+b1), gir1.2-polkit-1.0:amd64 (124-1), libportal-gtk4-1:amd64 (0.7.1-5), gir1.2-mediaart-2.0:amd64 (1.9.6-1+b1), python3-distro-info:amd64 (1.7), python3-jwt:amd64 (2.7.0-1), gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64 (45.0.1-3), libgtksourceview-4-0:amd64 (4.8.4-5+b2), gir1.2-gnomebg-4.0:amd64 (44.0-2+b1), libgnome-autoar-gtk-0-0:amd64 (0.4.4-2+b2), gir1.2-evince-3.0:amd64 (45.0-1+b1), libytnef0:amd64 (2.1.2-1+b1), gir1.2-xdp-1.0:amd64 (0.7.1-5), bogofilter-bdb:amd64 (1.2.5-1+b3), libosinfo-1.0-0:amd64 (1.11.0-2+b1), gir1.2-rsvg-2.0:amd64 (2.58.0+dfsg-1), libchamplain-0.12-0:amd64 (0.12.21-1+b1), gir1.2-soup-3.0:amd64 (3.4.4-5+b1), gir1.2-goa-1.0:amd64 (3.49.0-1), nautilus-data:amd64 (45.2.1-4), bogofilter-common:amd64 (1.2.5-1+b3), gir1.2-gweather-4.0:amd64 (4.4.0-1), gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0:amd64 (1.90.2-8), libgtksourceview-4-common:amd64 (4.8.4-5), gir1.2-grilo-0.3:amd64 (0.3.16-1+b2), libgnome-autoar-0-0:amd64 (0.4.4-2+b2), bogofilter:amd64 (1.2.5-1+b3), python3-gi-cairo:amd64 (3.48.2-1), gir1.2-gck-2:amd64 (4.2.0-3), libpst4:amd64 (0.6.76-1), gir1.2-nma4-1.0:amd64 (1.10.6-3), evolution-common:amd64 (3.50.3-1), gnome-session-common:amd64 (45.0-2), gir1.2-gcr-4:amd64 (4.2.0-3)

Note: I fixed the issue by executing:
apt-get install gdm3 nautilus software-properties-gtk task-gnome-desktop p7zip-full


I haven’t examined your upgrade in detail, but given that a number of package upgrades or replacements are related to the 64-bit time_t transition, it’s likely that that’s what caused all those package removals.
The transition itself is mostly transparent on amd64, but to allow package migrations from unstable to testing on architectures where it isn’t transparent, a number of packages have been removed from testing; the result is that currently, a large-scale package migration from unstable to testing is in progress, but isn’t complete. This means that upgrades in some scenarios can’t be completed without removing packages. This is a temporary situation, but obviously some people get caught in the cross-fire.
You could avoid this by running apt upgrade instead of apt-get dist-upgrade; the former won’t remove packages. As a general rule, apt upgrade is fine for day-to-day upgrades, and dist-upgrade should only be used if apt upgrade can’t fully upgrade a system, and then only with caution since it can end up removing a lot of packages.

Thanks, this sounds reasonable, as the time frame is consistent. The last successful apt-get dist-upgrade had been run on 2024-04-25. It had installed libssl3t64:amd64 and removed libssl3:amd64, for example, which appears to be part of the transition. The next update removed the crucial packages. Thanks as well for the apt upgrade tip, I was not aware of that!
